# If Customer/Client complaints that report not loading properly in SSRS then as a developer what to do first?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, report, msbi

If Customer/Client complaints that report not loading properly in SSRS then as a developer what to do first?

Comment: Understand the customer's definition of "properly." Is it displaying an error message? Is it displaying incorrect data? Is it just taking too long to display something? Only then can you determine: is it a training issue, or something that really needs to be fixed?

Comment: We need some details before we can attempt to answer. What should the report do? What does the customer say it is doing instead?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.